# Mysql alchemy filter

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter a query in mysql alchemy by doing something like this:

```
query_train = DBSession.query(TokenizedLabel).filter_by(which_disaster!=opts.disaster).all()
```

But it does not seem to work. Is there a way to filter a query where you are looking for somehting that is not equal to something else -> filter where which_disaster != "irene"

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[filter_by()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) cannot handle `not equal` (`!=`), use [filter()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) instead:

```
query_train = DBSession.query(TokenizedLabel).filter(TokenizedLabel.which_disaster!=opts.disaster).all()
```